# Update code MySQL to MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

php shows me an error to start using the MSQLI function. As would be the correct way to use it? Now try and documentaciond according to php.net but I can not choose the table

**Connect to db**

```
    function ConectarBD() {
      $vServidor="localhost";
      $vUsuarioBD="root";
      $vClaveBD="";
      $vNombreBD="admin";

      $vConexion=mysql_connect($vServidor, $vUsuarioBD, $vClaveBD);          

      if ($vConexion!=false) {

      $vSeleccionoBD=mysqli_select_db($vConexion,$vNombreBD);
        if ($vSeleccionoBD!=false) {

        return true; 
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Choose table and get array**

```
function CrearListados($vTabla) {

  $vListado=array();

  if (!ConectarBD()) {
    die ('Error en la conexion');
    return false;    

  }else {

    $vConsulta="SELECT * FROM provincias";
    $vRegistros = mysql_query($vConsulta);
    if(!$vRegistros){ 
      echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error().'<br />';
      return false;

    }else {
      $i=1;
      while ($vCadaRegistro = mysql_fetch_row($vRegistros)){
        $vListado[$i]['ID']=$vCadaRegistro[0];
        $vListado[$i]['provincia']= utf8_encode($vCadaRegistro[1]);
        $i++;
      }

      return $vListado;

    }
    DesconectarBD();
  }
}
```

This function use in signup.php :

```
<?php    
   $Registros=array();
   $Tabla="provincia";

   $Registros=CrearListados($Tabla);

   if (!empty($Registros) ){   
     $cntRegistros=count($Registros);
?>

<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="provincia">
        <option value="0">Seleccione una provincia</option>

        <?php for ($i=1; $i<$cntRegistros; $i++) { ?>                      

        <option value="<?php echo $Registros[$i]['ID']; ?>" <?php if (!empty($_POST['provincia']) && $_POST['provincia']==$i) {echo 'selected';} ?> ><?php echo $Registros[$i]['provincia']; ?></option>
        <?php } } ?>                        

    </select>
</div>
```

online: http://www.nicogaldo.com.ar/sesiones/signup.php

**edit:** change the function "mysql" to "mysqli", other changes have to do?

Comment: You are not using mysqli... Maybe it will work, when you specify the dbname in the constructor of mysqli.

Comment: please post your error, is ConectarBD file included wher you are runing quries, please use pdo or mysqli instead of mysql.

Comment: updated my question, please check

Comment: PHP's mysql is deprecated, you need to switch to mysqli or PDO. There are a ton of Q&A on SO or tutorials elsewhere to help you with that. Adding a single `i` in `mysql_connect` won't do it, you need to rewrite everything related to mysql.

Comment: this is making my head hurt. I would have to re-write all the functions :S

Comment: @nicogaldo Yes, you need to.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that hard to switch over to mysqli, most are similar:

**ConectarBD**

```
function ConectarBD() {
    $vServidor="localhost";
    $vUsuarioBD="root";
    $vClaveBD="";
    $vNombreBD="admin";

    $vConexion=mysqli_connect($vServidor, $vUsuarioBD, $vClaveBD, $vNombreBD);        

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    /* select database */
    //$vSeleccionoBD=mysqli_select_db($vConexion,$vNombreBD);

    return $vConexion;
}
```

**CrearListados**

```
function CrearListados($vTabla) {
$conn = ConectarBD();
$vConsulta = "SELECT ID, provincia FROM provincias";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn , $vConsulta)) {

    /* execute statement */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $provincia);

    /* fetch values */
    $vListado = array();
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        //printf ("%s (%s)\n", $id, $provincia);
        $vListado['ID'][]= $id;
        $vListado['provincia'][]= utf8_encode($provincia);
    }

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
/* close connection */
mysqli_close($conn);

return $vListado;
}
```

Comment: update file according to your answer, but it seems that something keeps failing. Watch the [site](http://nicogaldo.com.ar/sesiones/signup.php), I think it's a problem with the server, when I get home I will try with localhost

Comment: `mysqli_connect($vServidor, $vUsuarioBD, $vClaveBD, $vNombreBD);`  try connecting directly using the database. see my edit

Comment: thanks for your time. I've updated the functions but the error is still there.

Comment: `Access denied for user` thats the error for invalid credential, I can only suggest you to make sure the info is correct also user should have permission

Comment: there was a blank space in the database name :@  The functions are updated and uploaded to the site. Check because I'm not getting the array to select. I checked the table names and fields and are well. Visit the [site](http://www.nicogaldo.com.ar/sesiones/signup.php)

Comment: @nicogaldo before you return do a dump `var_dump($vListado)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60844/discussion-between-meda-and-nicogaldo).